# Using other HTTP connectors with JBoss 5.1

Tags: tomcat, jboss5.x, connector

I'm trying to use a "better" HTTP connector than JBoss' default `HTTP/1.1` connector. Following [BalusC's recommendations](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html#UseNIO), I changed the connector in `server.xml` to:

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                 port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
                 connectionTimeout="20000"
                 redirectPort="8443"
                 compression="force" />
```

But JBoss throws a `ClassNotFoundException` when it starts - I must be missing a JAR. (It looks like the NIO connector requires Tomcat 6, but I can't find what Tomcat version that JBoss 5.1 comes with... <sub><sup>grumble, @#$%^ing JBoss documentation</sup></sub>)

```
11:43:19,034 ERROR [Connector] Protocol handler instantiation failed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol from BaseClassLoader@1ed3e5f ... blah blah blah ...
11:43:19,263 INFO  [AprLifecycleListener] The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin; ... lots more classpath stuff...
```

After a bunch of Googling, it looks like that might not actually be the right connector to use. [This jboss.org thread](http://community.jboss.org/thread/39373) makes me think I should use the APR connector instead. That said, I don't really see the difference between the two.

Which connector is the right one, and how do I get it set up properly?

Answer (score 0):

Nio connection is no better than the standard connector. It just has non-blocking functionality.

APR-connector is a native implementation, so should be somewhat faster. It also supports SSL better (more configuration options and encryptions).

The configuration of APR-connection depends on the version of tomcat.

To find out the version of tomcat create a JSP file with content:

```
<%= application.getServerInfo() %>
```

Comment: Non-blocking functionality is definitely a plus for me, since it doesn't create a thread for every request, so it scales better. My app is fairly Ajax- and comet-heavy. Does APR provide this as well?

Comment: `<%= application.getServerInfo() %>` printed `JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA`. It turns out that JBoss doesn't include Tomcat, but a _fork_ of Tomcat, which they call JBoss Web. It looks like JBoss Web 2.1.x _and_ 3.0.x both correspond to (I guess, are forks of?) Tomcat 6.0. http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/